# Why does Microsoft Sam randomly quit talking if given a long body of text to recite?

Tags: windows-xp, text-to-speech

When given a large amount of text to recite, he stops randomly and does not resume where he left off.

How can I stop this from happening?

```
OS: Windows XP
Apps: This problem happens in both Wordpad and Notepad
```

Comment: can you add some more details about your machine, operating system, and versions of applications please.

Comment: @Nick Josevski Done!